# How can I pass ECPublicKey over socket in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have been trying to pass `PublicKey` via `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` in java Socket Programming but failed due to non-serializable Exception. Is there a way to send it through socket programming in Java??

Answer (score 0):

Just send the bytes, obtained via `getEncoded(),` and reconstruct it at the other end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already tried that....   Actually I m using de.FlexiProvider to generate ECC's public and private key..... So while reconstructing the keys from their corresponding byte array it shows de.flexiprovider.api.keys.ECKeyFactory.class not found...